# Android Application within another Application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

Maps or Latitude application in the Android Mobile.I want to make use of these applications into my application.
Just want to know whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean launching these apps from within your app. For Launching the Maps app you can use the following Intent

```
Intent URI :(one of the following)
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

Intent Action : VIEW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the Google Maps library.
Take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).